# create Custom field for tv series

Tags: customization

I want create a tv series website but i don't know how to list all seasons and episodes on one page like :

My GAME Season 1 
Episode 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9 - 10

My GAME Season 2 
Episode 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9 - 10

or this website :  streamxd.com/series/mon-oncle-charlie-streaming/117

and when click on episode get the player

Answer (score 2):

Use custom posts types with a hierarchical structure. So the Parent would be the Season 1 and then the child would be episodes. There are some plugins that build custom posts types with hierarchical structures, or reference codex. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type